# regex how to find a line with a word started with xxxx

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I have many some files which have such kind of line

```
#include <xxxx/nnnnn/xxxx_files_names.h>
```

I want search this pattern with grep and file also have content such test xxxx_files_names_yyyy. But I don't want  xxxx_files_names_yyyy in my grep search. I want only

```
#include <xxxx/nnnnn/xxxx_files_names.h>
```

Comment: the easiest way to achieve what I think you want is `grep xxxx file | grep -v yyyy`. You can really waste a lot of time trying to build a reg-ex that does both in one process. It's just not worth it (IMHO). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Simple grep should be good, as explained by @Shellter. I will add the test and results for ease of understanding,
I am searching across 3 files test1.txt,test2.txt and test3.txt you can leave it with the wildcard "*" to search globally in the folder.

When searching for the pattern it returns all matched pattern,grep doesn't care about what is prefixed/suffixed to the pattern, the whole line is returned.

```
 $grep "india" test*
    test1.txt:india.a
    test1.txt:india_a
    test1.txt:india_z
    test2.txt:india.a
    test2.txt:india_a
    test2.txt:india_z
    test3.txt:india.a
    test3.txt:india_a
    test3.txt:india_z
```

When an exact match is searched lines from the file with matches are being returned.

```
$grep "india_a" test*
test1.txt:india_a
test2.txt:india_a
test3.txt:india_a
```

A different way to exclude a specfic pattern is by using "grep -v" as below, which will exclude lines with the pattern from the output returned by the first grep.

```
$grep "india" test* | grep -v "india_z"
test1.txt:india.a
test1.txt:india_a
test2.txt:india.a
test2.txt:india_a
test3.txt:india.a
test3.txt:india_a
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick and dirty, as shellter suggested in comment:

```
grep 'xxxx' file | grep -v 'yyyy'
```

I call this "dirty", because if the `yyyy` is part of your path, it will be filtered out as well, which is not desired.

#### Using grep -P and negative look behind

```
kent$  cat ff
#include <xxxx/nnnnn/xxxx_files_names.h> 
#include <xxxx/yyyy/xxxx_files_names.h>  <-we want it!
#include <xxxx/nnnnn/xxxx_files_names_yyyy.h> 

kent$  grep -P 'xxxx.*(?<!yyyy)[.]h' ff
#include <xxxx/nnnnn/xxxx_files_names.h> 
#include <xxxx/yyyy/xxxx_files_names.h>  <-we want it!
```